# I'm having issues with my camera jittering in Unity 3D (2021.3.5f1)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm using Unity 3d (2021.3.5f1) and I'm having trouble getting my camera script to work properly. I'm having issues with my camera jittering, whenever I move it the camera jumps to a different rotation.

I originally had my camera attached to my player object, but looking at a few tutorials online, moved the camera over onto its own object. I thought that maybe there was an error getting both the player and the camera to move at the same time; but unfortunately, that didn't seem to solve the bug. I've been trying my best to figure out how to fix it but I can't figure out the source of the bug; any advice would help greatly.

Here is an image of my hierarchy
[Unity hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fq5w.png)

Here is the code for my camera movement.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEditor.Experimental.GraphView;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Camera Settings
    [Header("Camera Settings")]
    public float mouseSensitivity;

    //Rotational Variables
    private float rotX;
    private float rotY;

    //Objects
    [Header("Objects")]
    public GameObject player;

    //Misc
    private bool isGrounded;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Get Inputs
        float xMouse = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float yMouse = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        //Get isGrounded
        isGrounded = player.GetComponent<PlayerControl>().isGrounded;

        rotY += xMouse;
        rotX -= yMouse;

        //Clamp the Y Rotation (Only if grounded)
        if (isGrounded == true)
        {
            rotX = Mathf.Clamp(rotX, -90f, 90f);
        }
       
        //Apply the Rotation
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotX, rotY, 0);
        player.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * xMouse);


    }
}
```

Comment: try commenting out the "Mathf.Clamp" line of code and see if that fixes it. if not, try commenting out other logic until you find the culprit.